# Setting time with minutes using date ();

Tags: php, wordpress

So I have this code that works perfectly:

```
 <?php
    $time = date("H");
    $timezone = date("e");
    if ($time < "13") {
        echo "message1";
    } else
    if ($time >= "13" && $time < "19") {
        echo "message2";
    } else
    if ($time >= "19" && $time < "24") {
        echo "message3";
    }
    ?>
```

The problem is that I can only use hours: 1, 5, 10, 19 and etc.

I need to use minutes as well, eg. 13:30.

I have tried changing to 13:30. Also tried changing to 1350.

But can't make it work.

Need help.

Comment: You need to include the minutes in the time variable as well. `date("H")` only gets the hour. Add minutes to the format.

Comment: `date(“H”)` will return only the hours of a date stamp. Have you reviewed the documentation for [`date()`](https://php.net/date)? It’s not clear how you expect to get the minutes in `$time` without modifying the format first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new variable that hold the current minute,

[`DateTime::format`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) shows us that `date("i")` gives:

> Minutes with leading zeros

With the current hour and minute,  you can calculate any time, for example:

```
<?php
    $hour = date("H");
    $minute = date("i");
    
    // Between 13:30 and 13:30
    if ($hour === 13 && $minute <= 30) {
        echo "message1";
    } 

    // Between 13:30 and 19:00
    elseif (($hour >= 13 && $minute >= 30) && $hour < 19) {
        echo "message2";
    } 

    // After 19:00
    else {
        echo "message3";
    }
    ?>
```